# Maven meta-inf build setting, Java project

Tags: java, maven, jenkins

I have a parent pom for our project that has

```
<properties>
    <build.number></build.number>
...
</properties>
```

Then in one of the child projects, I have this in the pom

```
<configuration>
     ...           
    <archive>
        <manifestEntries>
        <Specification-Title>${project.name}</Specification-Title>
        <Specification-Version>${project.version}</Specification-Version>
        <Implementation-Version>${build.number}</Implementation-Version>
        </manifestEntries>
    </archive>
...
</configuration>
```

I'm basically trying to follow [this tutorial](https://tedvinke.wordpress.com/2013/04/20/using-jenkins-build-version-with-maven/) to have the build number get generated when our Jenkins build completes.  I created my

```
project
-- src
   -- main
      -- resource
         -- META-INF
```

folder that has nothing in it.  When I run

```
mvn clean install -Dbuild.number=123
```

the .war gets packaged and if I unpack that war, in the META-INF folder, I see that the MANIFEST.MF file does have the `Implementation-Version: 123` set.  However, I also want to have this property accessible through our api.  I'm not sure if I have this set up correctly because I thought that it would create a MANIFEST.MF file that I could use that was not part of the `.war`.

Comment: Can you show your full pom file?

Comment: @khmarbaise which one? or is there a part you are looking for (like the top portion versus the dependencies stuff)